# Proof of a regular parallelogram

Tags: geometry

Given any figure with four vertices and four straight edges, prove that one can construct a perfect parallelogram by connecting the midpoints of such figure.
This to me is a very fundamental and interesting geometry problem.

How would I begin to prove this?

Comment: (Spoilers: This is called [Varignon's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varignon%27s_theorem).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do it for a convex quadrilateral, since the diagram will be nicer. Call the vertices, listed in counterclockwise order, $A,B,C,D$. Draw the diagonal $AC$. The line joining the midpoints of $AB$ and of $BC$ is parallel to $AC$. This is by a basic property of triangles: the line joining the midpoints of two sides is parallel to the third side. The line joining the midpoints of  $AD$ and $CD$ is, for the same reason, parallel to $AC$.  So the two lines  are parallel *to each other*.

Now draw the diagonal $BD$ and use the same argument.

**Another way:** If you like to play with vectors, you can give an alternate proof. Think of $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ as vectors. The midpoint of $AB$ is $(A+B)/2$. The midpoint of $BC$ is $(B+C)/2$. The difference is $(A-C)/2$.

Similarly, the midpoint of $AD$ is $(A+D)/2$. The midpoint of $CD$ is $(C+D)/2$. The difference is $(A-C)/2$, which gives the parallelism.